# How to set bind9 docker container as dns of other container

Tags: docker, ssl, networking

I'm trying to set up ssl for my home network and I've set up a `bind9` container with a custom domain that points to my unraid server. So far so good. I've also set up a private `step-ca` certificate authority which needs it's dns set to the `bind9` container so that it knows about my private domain. The setup works if I set the dns of the step container to the internal docker ip address of the bind container but since these ip addresses are ephemeral I can't rely on that hence why I'm binding the bind9 ip address to something within `192.168.0.1/24` and accessing it there. This works if I set the dns server of my pc to the bind9 container but I am unable to do so for other docker containers for some reason

in short, `step-ca` and my proxy `traefik` need their dns set to `bind9` which I want to have set up with a static ip address on the `192.168.0.1/24` subnet. `traefik` also needs to be able to talk to containers on the  bridge network `br0` otherwise it won't be able to proxy requests to the containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addresses of your containers don't need to be ephemeral. We can set up a custom network using the [`networks` top-level element](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks-top-level-element) that defines a static range for the network using the [`ipam` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipam), and then we can assign our containers static address on this network.

We can use the [`dns` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dns) to configure containers to use the `bind9` container for name resolution.

Here's an example `docker-compose.yaml` that sets  up a `bind9` container and a couple of additional containers that will use it for DNS:

```
version: "3"

services:
  bind9:
    image: docker.io/internetsystemsconsortium/bind9:9.19
    volumes:
      - "./bind:/etc/bind"
      - bind9_cache:/var/cache/bind
      - bind9_log:/var/log
      - bind9_lib:/var/lib/bind
    networks:
      bind9:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.133.10

  web1:
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest
    networks:
      bind9:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.133.20
    dns: 192.168.133.10

  web2:
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest
    networks:
      bind9:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.133.21
    dns: 192.168.133.10

networks:
  bind9:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.133.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.133.1

volumes:
  bind9_cache:
  bind9_lib:
  bind9_log:
```

In in the `bind` directory, I have `bind` configured to serve the following zonefile:

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA docker.example. root.docker.example. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns.docker.example.
ns  IN  A   192.168.133.10
web1    IN  A   192.168.133.20
web2    IN  A   192.168.133.21
web IN  A   192.168.133.20
web IN  A   192.168.133.21
```

From either the `web1` or `web2` containers, we can confirm that they are using our bind instance for name resolution:

```
/ $ wget -O- web1.docker.example:8080
Connecting to web1.docker.example:8080 (192.168.133.20:8080)
writing to stdout
<html>
.
.
.
</html>
```

Recall that `docker-compose` is just a fancy wrapper for `docker run`, so you can accomplish the same thing without using `docker-compose` (although it will of course make life much easier).

---

If you need to access the `bind9` container, you would of course just publish the appropriate ports on your host by adding the necessary `ports` section to the compose configuration (or by using the `--publish`/`-p` option on the `docker run` command line):

```
  bind9:
    image: docker.io/internetsystemsconsortium/bind9:9.19
    ports:
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "53:53/tcp"
    volumes:
      - "./bind:/etc/bind"
      - bind9_cache:/var/cache/bind
      - bind9_log:/var/log
      - bind9_lib:/var/lib/bind
    networks:
      bind9:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.133.10
```

Comment: So my reverse proxy traefik needs to be members of both br0 (macvlan 192.168.0.0/24) with a custom ip because of port collisions and a member of the custom docker network. The bind configuration also needs to be connected to both networks. My custom dns entry needs to be valid for both br0 and the custom network which to my knowledge isn't really possible. I think I might be able to get away with bind, step and traefik all on br0 while traefik also connects to the protected bridge network where it can automatically detect other services because of traefik docker.socket magic

Comment: As long as my dns and CA and proxy are on the same network we're all good I think. Services behind the proxy can live in a bridge network with no exposed ports while traefik connects to both networks